# TikZ - Wire wrapped around doughnut

Tags: tikz-pgf

[image]

How might I go about generating a two-dimensional 'doughnut' with a wire wrapped around it, like the above image? (sorry for poor quality).

I tried playing around with `coil` in the pathmorphing library, but I was unable to get a satisfactory result, and I'm not sure how I would hide the 'back' of the wire.

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw(0,0)circle(1);
  \draw(0,0)circle(2);
  \draw[decorate,decoration={coil, amplitude=20, segment length=20}](0,0)circle(1.5);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please show us the TeX code you have tried so far! The we do not have to guess what you are doing ...